# Jenkins pipeline script for passing variables from one function to another function

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am new to Jenkins pipeline scripting. I am developing a Jenkins pipeline in which the Jenkins code is as follows. The logic looks like this:

```
node{
a=xyz
b=abc
//defined some global variables
   stage('verify'){
      verify("${a}","${b}")
      abc("${a}","${b}")
      echo "changed values of a and b are ${a} ${b}"
 }}
def verify(String a, String b)
{ //SOme logic where the initial value of a and b gets changed at the end of this function} 
def verify(String a, String b){
//I need to get the changed value from verify function and manipulate that value in this function}
```

I need to pass the initial `a` and `b`(multiple) values to the `verify` function and pass the changed value on to the other function. I then need to manipulate the changed value, and pass it to the stage in the pipeline where echo will display the changed values. How can I accomplish all this?

Comment: If you only need to verify a variable's value it would be simpler to check just one variable at a time and return the changed value so you could write something like `a = verify_a(a) ; b = verify_b(b)`

Comment: Thanks for reply but where should i give that and how it will pass to second and to the stage later. It would be greatful if you can show the sample for the above code

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's what I meant:

```
def String verify_a(String a) { /* stuff */ }

def String verify_b(String b) { /* stuff */ }

node {
    String a = 'xyz'
    String b = 'abc'

    stage('verify') {
        a = verify_a(a)
        b = verify_b(b)

        echo "changed values of a and b are $a $b"
    }

    stage('next stage') {
        echo "a and b retain their changed values: $a $b"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I have found to pass variables between stages is to just use Environment Variables. The one - admittedly major - restriction is that they can only be Strings. But I haven't found that to be a huge issue, especially with liberal use of the `toBoolean()` and `toInteger()` functions. If you need to be passing maps or more complex objects between stages, you might need to build something with external scripts or writing things to temporary files (make sure to stash what you need if there's a chance you'll switch agents). But env vars have served me well for almost all cases.

[This article is, as its title implies, the definitive guide on environment variables in Jenkins.](https://e.printstacktrace.blog/jenkins-pipeline-environment-variables-the-definitive-guide/) You'll see a comment there from me that it's really helped me grok the intricacies of Jenkins env vars.